# How can i make this media query work to see the menu vertically?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I created this small icon menu with the help of a tutorial and I am trying to make it responsive, but it is not working.

When the width is 400px I want the menu to be vertical.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.cuadro {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cuadro a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.cuadro a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.active {
  background-color: purple !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .cuadro {
    position: fixed;
    width: 414px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px
  }
  .cuadro a {
    background-color: pink;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
  }
  .cuadro a:hover {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .active {
    background-color: purple !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea180863a6.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cuadro">
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-spotify" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost good, simply make the menu item `float:none` and `width:100%` in the media query. You may also add `box-sizing:border-box` to avoid having overflow issue and you don't need to specify a width for `.cuadro` inside the media query :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.cuadro {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}

.cuadro a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.cuadro a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.active {
  background-color: purple !important;
}

@media all and (max-width: 414px) {
  .cuadro {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px
  }
  .cuadro a {
    background-color: pink;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
    float:none;
  }
  .cuadro a:hover {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea180863a6.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="cuadro">
    <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-spotify" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, i love this social media site :)

Comment: @OlmedoGuzman welcome :) i also added more rectification, you can have a look ;)

Comment: @OlmedoGuzman are you sure you copied the code correctly ? as i am trying on chrome and it's fine for me

Comment: when i use the toogle device bar (ctrl+shift+m) it does not work, but i try to resize the window and it worked fine

Comment: @OlmedoGuzman it's because you used `only screen` on media query. Change it to `all`. I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of repetition in your CSS. There's no need to declare rules twice.

An alternative to `float` is to use `flexbox`. Note that you only need to change the direction of the container for smaller screens.

[Good introduction to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**example**

I've removed / changed a few styles.. let me know if you have questions.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.cuadro {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
}

.cuadro a {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.cuadro a:not(.active):hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.active {
  background-color: purple;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
  .cuadro {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea180863a6.js"></script>
<div class="cuadro">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-spotify" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i am new in this, i will try to avoid to repeat the code!

Comment: The snippet above works for me in Chrome... what isn't working?

Comment: when i use the toogle device bar (ctrl+shift+m) it does not work, but i try to resize the window and it worked fine

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're describing, but maybe you need to add this meta tag to your `head`: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`